# How to install and use couch db in android

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

How i should install and use couch Db in android.
I mean local couch Db which i can use in tablet as well as emulator.What all steps i must follow to do so.

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on a project using this at the moment. There are two options:

1) couchbase-android. (yes, couchbase, it's actually couchDB. Go figure)

[See This Link](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase)

This is what I use. This is just stock couchDB 1.2.0, bundled with an erlang vm for android. I've found it to be flawlessly stable (despite being beta). Big drawback is that it takes ~4 sec to start the app up, as it has to load the erlang emulator. The readme instructions are good.

It is no longer being developed, in favor of ...

2) TouchDB android. [Check Out](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android)

This is couchDB rewritten in java, so it runs and boots faster on android. There is TouchDB for iOS, which is the same thing in objective-c. I was put off by the development status, but have heard that it's not so bad. The iOS version has had heavy development lately, and is at version 1.0. I hear things like "some features aren't implimented", but not which features those are. Supposedly this will just drop in and replace couchbase-android.

I can attest that couchbase-android works well (if you don't mind the boot time). I have developed my app with cordova, which I am happy to give advice about if that's the way you're going.

Comment: Update on TouchDB. It's been renamed Couchbase-Lite. The android project can be found at https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android and the ios version at https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios.    If you want more information on the naming history (It is a bit confusing.) see https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/Why-Couchbase-Lite.

Answer (score 1):

Couch DB also have android project which can be found [here.](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase) They have full source code with code sample and instruction on how it can be added in java project...

Also check out following post:

[Confused on how to use CouchDB on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343868/confused-on-how-to-use-couchdb-on-android)

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide on http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/cbl-android-1.0b2/ and you won't have any problems.

It's pretty straightforward and clean.