# How to use mysql in an offline app?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to use mysql in my app. But my app is offline app not online app. Can I do this? Do I use JSON? If I use JSON my app must connect to internet? I want to use mysql but my app isn't require internet connection.

Comment: You don't need an internet connection to use a sql db on android. Please explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to add mysql (not sqlite) in my app. But I don't know how. If I use JSON, as i know the app is must use internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run an instance of the Data Base locally in the device.

Even if I don't know of any MySQL I can advice you to use [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB): see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499205/how-to-install-and-use-couch-db-in-android) and other similar question. With couched you can use JSON data and noSQL capability.

Comment: JSON is a data format.. what are you meaning with this? It is like to say: "Can I use English?" and the answer is "Yes you can use English both in writing book (offline) and in phone calls (connected to the network)"

Comment: I think JSON always need internet. I don't know what JSON is. If I hear JSON, I always think if I use JSON.. the app/website must connect internet

Comment: But, I want to use mysql. So, I need other answer

Comment: It is better to understand a little bit what you are asking before to ask. Good luck!